# Codeigniter url does not work on the web server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was developing in XAMPP environment on my local machine, and everything is fine. I can access my controller like this:

`localhost/myproject/index.php/catalog/home/get`

`catalog` is the sub folder under `controllers`.

However, after I uploaded my project to the server. I should be able to access my page by the following url:

`http://www.example.com/index.php/catalog/home/index`

but this gives me a 404 page.

The only url works is the default page I defined in the `route.php` file:

`$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`

In the `config.php`, I set my base_url to be `http://www.example.com/`

All my controllers' first letter are capitalized and I'm using CI 3.1X. My server is a linux which uses nginx instead of apache. I tried to modify or delete my .htaccess file, but it doesn't solve my problem.

I'm not looking for an exact answer, I would like to know how to debug my code in this situation.

Here is an example of one of my controllers:

```
<?php

class Survey extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('catalog/model_survey');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $error = $this->input->get('error');

        if (isset($error)) {
            $data['error'] = true;
        } else {
            $data['error'] = false;
        }

        $data['action'] = "index.php/catalog/success";
        $data['base'] = base_url();

        $this->load->view('catalog/survey', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
application
|-- cache
|-- config
|-- controllers
|   |-- admin
|   |   |-- common
|   |   |-- redpacket
|   |   |-- setting
|   |   `-- tools
|   `-- catalog
|-- core
|-- helpers
|-- hooks
|-- language
|   |-- chinese
|   |   `-- admin
|   |       |-- common
|   |       |-- redpacket
|   |       |-- setting
|   |       `-- tools
|   `-- english
|       `-- admin
|           `-- common
|-- libraries
|-- logs
|-- models
|   |-- admin
|   |   |-- common
|   |   |-- redpacket
|   |   |-- setting
|   |   |-- tools
|   |   `-- user
|   `-- catalog
|-- third_party
`-- views
|-- admin
    |   |-- common
    |   |-- redpacket
    |   |-- setting
    |   `-- tools
    |-- catalog
    `-- errors
|-- cli
        `-- html
```

Comment: Have you used .htaccess file?

Comment: @NaimMalek Yes, by default there was a .htaccess file in the CI project folder. I tried to delete it, but the problem is still there

Comment: Please check filenames, you need to upload filename with First Letter Capital. e.g. ```Home.php```

Comment: @kishor10d My file names are good, I read your suggestion in many other posts. I don't think this is the reason in my case

Comment: It might be permission issue check your catalog folder's permission. @SSD

Comment: You have to set 755 permission to `catalog` folder

Comment: can you post some more code of your controller ```Home``` and ```index``` function?

Comment: @NaimMalek `catalog` file was already 755.

Comment: right now I'm wondering if this is a nginx issue, but I'm not really fimilar with nginx. No idea how to debug it. I have check the error. log of nginx, nothing is there

Comment: `/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log` here is the path of error log file. @SSD

Comment: please check your ```config.php``` for ```$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';``` is set or not.

Comment: @kishor10d yes, index_page is set by default

Comment: can you post your url, if its public portal??

Comment: Can you show me your nginx_error.log last error?

Comment: @NaimMalek last few errors were from April 27. Nginx doesn't know report anything related to my case

Comment: @kishor10d Don't know if you can access it or not, my portal is http://wx.hbesct.com. Is this because it is a second-level domain under my www.hbesct.com?

Comment: @SSD What is the permission of catalog folder/directory ? Can you show the output of "ls -la" command

Comment: @DeepakDixit Survey.php is under catalog, this is the permission it has `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  632 5 16 11:50 Survey.php`. `catalog` has a permission `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 5 16 15:56`

Comment: @SSD It looks like permissions are okay . Will you check the error log . Probably it will be at /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log .

Comment: I checked your url, it seems everything is correct. strange thing happening.

Comment: @kishor10d This is really frustrating right now. The page you see is the `default_controller` that I set in the `route.php`. This is the only thing works right now, all the other pages cannot be accessed by using the default url http://www.example.com/index.php/catalog/class/function

Comment: I hit full path for your files directly, it has to give error 403, but it is showing File not found error.
http://wx.hbesct.com/application/catalog/Survey.php

Hit this url.

Comment: @kishor10d That's because you missed the controllers file, the full path is actually http://wx.hbesct.com/application/controllers/catalog/Survey.php, and you will hit 500 error. Because you are access this single file, and it cannot recognize the `CI_Controller` class which it extends

Comment: @SSD : But at least, it has to show some error. It is showring *This page isn’t working* error. It has to show Access Forbidden message.

Comment: @SSD : Have you hosted this in **production** environment?

Comment: paste your .htaccess code plese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing my local environment and the production environment, I found that I'm using Apache on my local machine, but nginx on the server. Thus, I'm guessing the problem would be the setting of my nginx config file.

After doing some research, this is what I found online: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/?highlight=codeigniter

I modified my nginx config file to this, and everything works fine now. By using this config, it also get rid of the index.php in the url. You can access the web by type `http://www.example.com/survey`, or if you did what I did, adding a sub folder under controller, just simply add your sub folder in the url `http://www.example.com/catalog/survey`

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you forgot to update .htaccess file on the server

Comment: could you provide more information? how do I update it? this is what it looks like `<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>`

Comment: You need to look for htaccess used on your machine and install the same one on the server. Also check apache logs for 404 errors. It can show you actual reason of this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following checklist.

1. Check Controller file name `Survey.php`, `S` must be capital.
2. Check folder name `catalog` for case sensitivity.
3. Same for view and models.

I use following `.htaccess` code in most of my projects.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**Edited answer:**

In your given directory hierarchy, all your `controller` and `model` names are in lower case. As per the CI 3.X standard, the `Classes` first character is capitalized and the same is applicable for their respective files.

Comment: just tried your `.htaccess` code, doesn't work in my case

Comment: @SSD Could you please post your directory & file hierarchical structure screen shot.

Comment: @SSD I can see your catalog directory is empty, no controller is available. Again, you have posted `Survey.php` controller code, there is no file in the directory hierarchy you have posted. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

localhost/myproject/index.php/catalog/home/get

Here localhost is hostname,
myproject is project name
catalog is controller sub folder name,
home is controller name,
and get is function under home controller.

in Home make H capital as it is class name,
and check .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Credit to kishor10d in the comments. I wanted to highlight this as a possible solution:

If you are developing on a windows machine and deploying to a linux web server, the capitalization of the files is critical. Windows ignores case sensitivity and Linux requires a match. The fix for me was to capitalize the controller's filename.